# Actionscript 3 implementation of Random.Next()

Tags: actionscript-3, random

I was wondering if there is good implementation of Random.Next in AS-3.

Basically want to generate a series of Random numbers given a seed,and at times
minumum and maximum limits..

Similar to C# System.Random class.

```
Random random = new Random();  
return random.Next(min, max);
```

Thanks All.

Comment: i saw PRNG Random class in as3crypto package... is it same in usage as given by Grant Skinner? http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/source/browse/#svn/trunk/as3crypto/src/com/hurlant/crypto/prng

Comment: I believe so.  They are both using the Parker-Miller psuedo-random number algorithm.  Just different implementations.

Comment: any example or implementation of the same?

Comment: Sorry, what are you asking for?

Comment: example of how to use the as3crypto 'Random' class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grant has a random number class, and a seeded random number class:

Non seeded:
http://www.gskinner.com/blog/archives/2008/01/source_code_ran.html

Seeded:
http://www.gskinner.com/blog/archives/2008/01/source_code_see.html

Also, you can find a decent implementation here:

http://lab.polygonal.de/?p=162/

Example:

```
package{
  import flash.display.Sprite;
  import de.polygonal.math.PM_PRNG;

  public class RandomTest extends Sprite{

    public function RandomTest(){
      var random:PM_PRNG = new PM_PRNG();
      random.seed = 1234567890;
      for(var i:uint = 0; i< 10; i++){
        trace(random.nextDouble());
      }
      trace("----------");
      random = new PM_PRNG();
      random.seed = 1234567890;
      for(i = 0; i< 10; i++){
        trace(random.nextDouble());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This uses bitmapData and perlin noise - seems weird. Is there any better solution somewhere?

Comment: Found faster seeded implementation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654758/seedable-random-number-generator-actionscript/7658343?noredirect=1#comment29385803_7658343 Sorry i didn't linked to it earlier.

Comment: @mika And you down-voted me for that?  That's not what down-votes are for.  And comments aren't for posting answers either.  Add another answer if you think the solution you found is better.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is :

```
function randomNext(min:Number, max:Number):Number {
 return Math.random()*(max-min)+min;
}
```

Comment: We don't have make such utility functions into the standards flash API. This can be done easily like the example above. So it keeps the library small.

Comment: This is not a seeded random number.

Comment: @Joony: it is a seeded random number. But the seeding is not exposed through the API.

Comment: Well, yes, we're talking semantics now.  Not exposing the seeding makes the number non-repeatable (essentially completely random), and therefor useless in some circumstances.  The actual implementation is irrelevant if what I want is to seed a random number.  I should clarify my statement: "This is not a user seeded random number."  The question states "given a seed."  I think the inquirer is looking for repeatable results.

Answer (score 0):

There is a faster solution described here - not using bitmap data and perlin noise
[Seedable random number generator, actionscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654758/seedable-random-number-generator-actionscript/7658343?noredirect=1#comment29385803_7658343)