# How is a random number generated at runtime?

Tags: c#, algorithm, programming-languages, random

Since computers cannot pick random numbers(can they?) how is this random number actually generated. For example in C# we say,

```
Random.Next()
```

What happens inside?

Comment: Search - there are already dozens of answers to this question.

Comment: here is another topic covering asking for the as3 implementation of random.next: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930291/actionscript-3-implementation-of-random-next there are also code-snippets inside

Comment: @RogerG > Have you got a link to share? Because I didnt see any... @hacticks > thanks a lot

Comment: First two I found here that have conversation and additional links:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37702/true-random-number-generator    or   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/632873/why-is-it-hard-for-a-program-to-generate-random-numbers

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may checkout [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator). According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) the specific implementation used in .NET is based on Donald E. Knuth's subtractive random number generator algorithm. For more information, see [D. E. Knuth. "The Art of Computer Programming, volume 2: Seminumerical Algorithms". Addison-Wesley, Reading, MA, second edition, 1981](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201038226).

Comment: That's a really good article --- and it includes some links to source code that shows a few PRNGs, too, which is great.  +1

Answer (score 7):

> Since computers cannot pick random numbers (can they?)

As others have noted, "Random" is actually pseudo-random. To answer your parenthetical question: yes, computers can pick truly random numbers. Doing so is much more expensive than the simple integer arithmetic of a pseudo-random number generator, and usually not required. However there are applications where you *must* have non-predictable true randomness: cryptography and online poker immediately come to mind.  If either use a predictable source of pseudo-randomness then attackers can decrypt/forge messages much more easily, and cheaters can figure out who has what in their hands.

The .NET crypto classes have [methods that give random numbers suitable for cryptography](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator.aspx) or games where money is on the line. As for how they work: the literature on crypto-strength randomness is extensive; consult any good university undergrad textbook on cryptography for details.

Specialty hardware also exists to get random bits. If you need random numbers that are drawn from atmospheric noise, see www.random.org.

Comment: All computer/logic based RNG is pseudo-random *unless* they have a truly random source. A random source would be something like radioactive decay. Some computer hardware have random number generators that have transistors that are in an unstable state and create a constant stream of random bits. The difference between pseudo-random and random is pseudo-random is deterministic but pulls data from many sources are are very hard to predict and truly random is even if you know all the sources, you still can't know the output until it happens.

Comment: @Bengie: I believe the crypto classes derive their entropy from sources like keystroke timings and so on. Those are as random as you need them to be for practical purposes.

Comment: So the Crypto classes do have good sources of entropy? What about on servers where they're no human interaction and you can't use a human as a source of entropy? I know a good source of entropy is a dissected smoke detector with an unfiltered webcam pressed up against its radioactive part. Also works as a great screensaver. A nice stream of random bits  :-)

Comment: @Bengie: I do not know what the crypto classes do for their source of entropy. Keystroke timings are just one example of a possible source of entropy from within the system. If you are interested in the implementation details of the crypto classes, you should ask an expert on them.

Answer (score 5):

Knuth covers the topic of randomness very well.

We don't really understand random well.  How can something predictable be random?  And yet pseudo-random sequences can appear to be perfectly random by statistical tests.

There are three categories of Random generators, amplifying on the comment above.

First, you have pseudo random number generators where if you know the current random number, it's easy to compute the next one. This makes it easy to reverse engineer other numbers if you find out a few.

Then, there are cryptographic algorithms that make this much harder.  I believe they still are pseudo random sequences (contrary to what the comment above implies), but with the very important property that knowing a few numbers in the sequence does NOT make it obvious how to compute the rest.  The way it works is that crypto routines tend to hash up the number, so that if one bit changes, every bit is equally likely to change as a result.

Consider a simple modulo generator (similar to some implementations in C rand() )

int rand() {
  return seed = seed * m + a;
}

if m=0 and a=0, this is a lousy generator with period 1: 0, 0, 0, 0, ....
if m=1 and a=1, it's also not very random looking: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...

But if you pick m and a to be prime numbers around 2^16, this will jump around nicely looking very random if you are casually inspecting.  But because both numbers are odd, you would see that the low bit would toggle, ie the number is alternately odd and even.  Not a great random number generator.  And since there are only 2^32 values in a 32 bit number, by definition after 2^32 iterations at most, you will repeat the sequence again, making it obvious that the generator is NOT random.

If you think of the middle bits as nice and scrambled, while the lower ones aren't as random, then you can construct a better random number generator out of a few of these, with the various bits XORed together so that all the bits are covered well.  Something like:

(rand1() >> 8) ^ rand2() ^ (rand3() > 5) ...

Still, every number is flipping in synch, which makes this predictable.  And if you get two sequential values they are correlated, so that if you plot them you will get lines on your screen.  Now imagine you have rules combining the generators, so that sequential values are not the next ones.
For example

v1 = rand1() >> 8 ^ rand2() ...
v2 = rand2() >> 8 ^ rand5() ..

and imagine that the seeds don't always advance.  Now you're starting to make something that's much harder to predict based on reverse engineering, and the sequence is longer.

For example, if you compute rand1() every time, but only advance the seed in rand2() every 3rd time, a generator combining them might not repeat for far longer than the period of either one.

Now imagine that you pump your (fairly predictable) modulo-type random number generator through DES or some other encryption algorithm.  That will scramble up the bits.

Obviously, there are better algorithms, but this gives you an idea.  Numerical Recipes has a lot of algorithms implemented in code and explained.  One very good trick: generate not one but a block of random values in a table.  Then use an independent random number generator to pick one of the generated numbers, generate a new one and replace it.  This breaks up any correlation between adjacent pairs of numbers.

The third category is actual hardware-based random number generators, for example based on atmospheric noise

http://www.random.org/randomness/

This is, according to current science, truly random.  Perhaps someday we will discover that it obeys some underlying rule, but currently, we cannot predict these values, and they are "truly" random as far as we are concerned.

The boost library has excellent C++ implementations of Fibonacci generators, the reigning kings of pseudo-random sequences if you want to see some source code.

Answer (score 4):

I'll just add an answer to the first part of the question (the "can they?" part).h

Computers *can* generate (well, *generate* may not be an entirely accurate word) random numbers (as in, not pseudo-random). Specifically, by using environmental randomness which is gotten through specialized hardware devices (that generates randomness based on noise, for e.g.) or by using environmental inputs (e.g. hard disk timings, user input event timings).

However, that has no bearing on the second question (which was how `Random.Next()` works).

Answer (score 2):

The `Random` class is a [pseudo-random number generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator).

It is basically an extremely long but deterministic repeating sequence. The "randomness" comes from starting at different positions. Specifying where to start is done by choosing a [seed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed) for the random number generator and can for example be done by using the system time or by getting a random seed from another random source. The [default Random constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9.aspx) uses the system time as a seed.

The actual algorithm used to generate the sequence of numbers is documented in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx):

> The current implementation of the Random class is based on Donald E. Knuth's subtractive random number generator algorithm. For more information, see D. E. Knuth. "The Art of Computer Programming, volume 2: Seminumerical Algorithms". Addison-Wesley, Reading, MA, second edition, 1981.

Comment: So, one would not want to use the C# Random class for cryptographic functions, then, it sounds like?  I presume there would be some sort of API available for getting such numbers, or would that require using a Win32 function via P/Invoke?

Comment: @Michael Trausch: You might want to look at RandomNumberGenerator instead for cryptographic purposes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Computers use [pseudorandom number generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator). Essentially, they work by start with a seed number and iterating it through an algorithm each time a new pseudorandom number is required.

The process is of course entirely deterministic, so a given seed will generate exactly the same sequence of numbers every time it is used, but the numbers generated form a statistically uniform distribution (approximately), and this is fine, since in most scenarios all you need is stochastic randomness.

The usual practice is to use the current system time as a seed, though if more security is required, "entropy" may be gathered from a physical source such as disk latency in order to generate a seed that is more difficult to predict. In this case, you'd also want to use a [cryptographically strong random number generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator) such as [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much details but what I know is that a seed is used in order to generate the random numbers it is then based on some algorithm that uses that seed that a new number is obtained.

If you get random numbers based on the same seed they will be the same often.