# How is the .net random generator implemented?

Tags: c#, .net

I mean the standard (?) random generator in .net  /c#

```
Random random = new Random(seed);
random.next();
```

I know there are tens or hundreds of methods in literature, but I cannot find out which one the .net framework uses currently?

Reason for asking question: if I draw a LOT of random variables, will I ever return to the same sequence. I know some RNG have this undesirable property.

Comment: You can [browse the framework source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667410.aspx) yourself, or just [decompile it](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx).

Comment: You can read the whole thing using justDecompile.  Or, hell, isn't that part of the framework open source now?

Comment: I'd bet it uses http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator, but I'm unable to find any proof

Comment: (guys above - do you think that OP will be able to recognize the algorithm from it's source?)

Comment: @Yossarian, it doesn't. That would be kind of the worst choice, anyway.

Comment: @usr, why? There are other implementations in framework available, that would give better results.

Comment: @willem all random number generators have a chance to come back to the same seed if you call them enough times. However, the RNG's list is so incredibly long that it is impractical to attempt to do so.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is a random number generated at runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440735/how-is-a-random-number-generated-at-runtime)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Pseudo-random numbers are chosen with equal probability from a finite
>   set of numbers. The chosen numbers are not completely random because a
>   definite mathematical algorithm is used to select them, but they are
>   sufficiently random for practical purposes. **The current implementation
>   of the Random class is based on a modified version of Donald E.
>   Knuth's subtractive random number generator algorithm.** For more
>   information, see D. E. Knuth. "The Art of Computer Programming, volume
>   2: Seminumerical Algorithms". Addison-Wesley, Reading, MA, second
>   edition, 1981.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx

Answer (score 1):

All calculations are based on seed. If you define a seed then for the same sequence of methods you will get the same results. If not then the default seed is the Environment.TickCount, therefore the same sequence of methods will generate different results on each run (not guaranteed in parallels).