# Seedable random number generator, actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, random

I am looking for a random number generator in actionscript 3.0 that i can seed.
The Math.random() does not have this functionality.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go
http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2008/01/source_code_see.html

Comment: @antiz Yeah people on here are brutal sometimes. I gave you both a +1 to offset it and then some.

Comment: Using a bitmap with perlin noise? I'm sure it works but it sounds quite hackish, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

I mostly use this seeded random function, which is very fast.

```
var seed:int = 777;

const MAX_RATIO:Number = 1 / int.MAX_VALUE;
const MIN_MAX_RATIO:Number = -MAX_RATIO;

function random():Number
{
   seed ^= (seed << 21);
   seed ^= (seed >>> 35);
   seed ^= (seed << 4);
   if (seed > 0) return seed * MAX_RATIO;
   return seed * MIN_MAX_RATIO;
}
```

sources:
http://blog.stroep.nl/2012/07/random-seed-actionscript/
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator

Comment: the link is dead. Could you explain a bit more about your answer? The other upvoted solution uses a bitmap data with perlin noise. I'm sure there must be something cleaner.

Comment: I added a link to my blog, with a simple example how to use this. Basically it shifts around numbers, which gives random seeming values, but in the same order if you use the same seed.

Comment: Is this supposed to only return negative numbers? When using this I had to change the second to last line from seed < 0 to seed > 0.

Comment: It is supposed to return a Number between 0-1. I updated the code in the answer to `if (seed > 0)`, not sure why I had the  `< 0` in the first place..

Comment: Now that is a helpful comment

Comment: What details else do you need?

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks for posting it! Works like a charm and absolutely should be the accepted answer because it's more concise and incredibly simple.